# Define a macro for inserting a \begin \end listings block

Tags: macros, listings

Can you define a macro that would take a `listings` code as a parameter and insert it inside a `\begin{lstlistings} \end{lstlistings}` block?

My idea is something like this:

```
\def\blist#1{\begin{lstlisting} #1 \end{lstlisting}}
```

so I could just write

```
\blist{ "this code is inside listings block" }
```

Comment: You can't to that in full generality in any case. The problem is that `lstlisting` is a (smart) variant of `verbatim` and such environments can *never* be the argument to a command.

Comment: I see. And would something like this `\def\blist{\begin{lstlisting}}
\def\elst{\end{lstlisting}}` work? `\blist TEXT TEXT \elst` gives me an error on `\elst`

Comment: Like `verbatim`, LaTeX must see an *explicit* `\end{lstlisting}` to end the job; so hiding it in a macro is not helpful.

Comment: You can, *to a very limited extent*, say `\def\blist#1{\lstlisting#1\endlstlisting}`. The "limited extent" is because LaTeX special characters such as `{`, `}`, `#`, `%` and `$` will not be interpreted as expected in a `lstlisting` environment. Are you perhaps looking for `\lstinline`?

Comment: I was thinking of more general use, not inline.

Comment: So, where's the advantage of using `\blist{<long series of statements>}` instead of the clearer `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}`?

Comment: Because I use it many times in my document so it'd be faster to type. Just escaping from the listings block won't do the trick.

Comment: @DavidL: Did you know that [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides an inline version: `\lstinline`, which works similar to your requested `\blist`. Alternatively, use `\let\blist\lstinline` and use `\blist`.

Comment: if you're wanting to type code faster, it sounds like you're using a not-very-powerful editor. Once you learn how to use something like `vim`, these kind of concerns go away

Comment: I'm using Tex for iPad, but it was more of trying what the LaTeX can do and cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first an input such as

```
\blist{<statement>
  <statement>
  <statement>
  <statement>}
```

can seem more appealing than

```
\begin{lstlisting}[<options>]
<statement>
<statement>
<statement>
<statement>
\end{lstlisting}
```

but eventually it doesn't reveal such. For one thing: `\end{lstlisting}` is much more evident in the input than a single brace.

Besides, there are technical reasons why the "macro with argument" is difficult to implement for `lstlisting`: this environment is pretty much like `verbatim` (but does more complicated things) and so it can't go inside the argument to another command, if you want that it treats correctly all the characters which are special to LaTeX (braces, `#`, `$` and `%`, in particular).

A good text editor can help, but also `listings` features: if you want to give particular options for typesetting chunks of code, you can define a new environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{blist}[1][]
  {\lstset{<common options>,#1}}
  {}
```

and then

```
\begin{blist}
<statement>
<statement>
<statement>
<statement>
\end{blist}
```

will be typeset applying the `<common options>`. Not very harder to type and good for *marking* your input and making it easy to find the chunks of code that use that common setting. You can also add "local options" by saying

```
\begin{blist}[<local options>]
```